# In search of a working, stable, headless browser for CI integration and local browser runs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automation, headless-browser

I'm looking for advice on the best way to test (via automation) an angular web app.

I've dug around on a lot of sites looking at what other people are doing. I've also set up a framework and coded a short suite of tests in Selenium/Jasmine/Protractor, which actually worked great. Until... I needed to integrate it into our CI builds headlessly. I tried PhantomJS, and while it occassionally runs to completion, it's incredibly buggy and unreliable for this task, or with this stack, or both. ;-).

I'm willing to change my stack and re-code a bit (we're not that deep into dev'ing) if I know I can meet the following parameters (in order of priority):

1. The code will run headlessly on our CI server, which is Win with TeamCity (we may port this to a Mac, so if it ran on that too... bonus points)
2. The code will run locally on my win box with major browsers
3. The code will run on Browserstack/Saucelabs (this is somewhat optional)

I have literally spent numerous days trying to get Phantom to play nice. The concept is great, but the support appears questionable, as does the implementation and followup. I have also hit multiple lists of headless browsers and none of them seem to meet what I need (though I have not actually tried any others, as of yet... I wanted to post this request for advice first).

So, is there a way to do this that will be reliable (at least as reliable as the code I write, that's really all I ask) and scalable across my requirements above?

I'm pretty new at testing angular sites, and to JS, and am completely open to any/all suggestions. 
Your thoughts are greatly appreciated.
 -- brent

Answer (score 0):

It appears your question already has answers.

I would suggest using protractor tool which would allow you running tests on real browsers. For End to end or integration test testing using protractor is great. 
For doing only unit tests Karma is good and can be done on real browser.

For CI tools getting access to real browser is hard, as not all vendor would offer that, so, using Saucelab would be handy there as it gives kind of cloud access to browsers and at same time allows you to access localhost url. You can run the same protractor and Karma tests on real browsers via Saucelabs on your CI platform.